# Is mysql fetch returning current data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am just asking to get sure: When I perform a mysql fetch-function in php (fetch_array, fetch_object, fetch_all, ...) can I trust on the function returning the current data?

In PHP-Manual I can read f.e. for fetch_object: "Returns the current row of a result set as an object".

An example Setup:

- a PHP script that traverses over about 100 table rows
- it needs about 5 seconds to update a single row (because it does some calculation or remote api-access in the meantime)
- there is a column with info that says "under progress"
- multiple processes running the same script

On this setup: Can I be sure that on each fetch I get the current "under progress" information which may be changed by another process?

You may think I'll point to table-locks or transactions but I got a list of orders which I send to another system per API-Call so I have to set an info-token to prevent other processes from reading and sending the same order.

Comment: I would not think so, `fetch()` (PDO, from manual) `Fetches the next row from a result set` and the result set is defined when you execute the query. Apart from that it would be weird if your results change while you are fetching them. It is easy to test though :-)

Comment: You should also read about .table level locking mechanism

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok I tried some variations and there seems no fetch-function is returning current data - the result-set seems to be predefined:

- mysql with fetch_object
- pdo with fetchObject
- and at least the following also does not do the trick!

  1. $stmt = "SELECT * FROM ..."
  2. foreach($pdo->query($stmt) as $row)

I may recall the db on each single loop or are there any more ideas?

**Edit:**

Thanks to all your answers and especially the comment by @Confused! I thought that table locking is only for write access but there is one for reading also. But I found locking on table-level is hard to identify by another session which is looking for if a single table is locked.

In my research I also found GET_LOCK() and RELEASE_LOCK() as "locking-tokens" (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) which are solving my question. This is my answer and solution (I will accept it in 2 days when I am allowed to do this)

Comment: yes, of course, if you are doing a fetch once in 5 seconds, you should recall the db

Comment: you see how it's important to ask straight to the point, on the actual problem you have to solve, instead of asking on the some wrong decision you made.

Comment: ok lets start a debate ;) When I asked the question I done that because I missed some knowledge on mysql handling. Now I know that the fetch is based on a predefined result-set and there is no chance to get current data only by fetch -> so now I got the solution that helped me. If you can see the question history you would know that it got 2 upvotes before it got downvoted. Now its your turn and feel free to downvote :D